# NLTK agreement with distance metric

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I have a task to calculate [inter-annotator agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-rater_reliability) in [multi-label classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification), where for each example more than one label can be assigned. I found that [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.metrics.html) can measure agreement based on a distance metric.

I am looking for an example of calculating krippendorff alpha with MASI distance.

This is what I have.

```
import nltk
from nltk.metrics import masi_distance


toy_data = [['1', 5723, [1,2]],['2', 5723, [2,3]]]

task = nltk.metrics.agreement.AnnotationTask(data=toy_data, distance=masi_distance)
print task.alpha()
```

This code fails with

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

The following doesn't work either:

```
toy_data = [['1', 5723, set([1,2])],['2', 5723, set([2,3])]]
```

Do you have a working example?
Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be more precise, what needs to be a frozenset (as @alexis has pointed out) is just the third member of the triple, this is the labels assigned to the item.

```
toy_data = [['1', 5723, frozenset(1,2)],['2', 5723, frozenset(2,3)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the data should be a list of tuples, not a list of lists (tuples are hashable, lists are not), try:

```
toy_data = [('1', 5723, (1,2)),('2', 5723, (2,3))]
```

(I made the values tuples instead of lists too in case that may be a problem as well)

Comment: It fails with error message AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'intersection', in addition, it's not just tuples, it can be more than two values.

Comment: The error message indicates that for some reason it needs a `frozenset`.